# Given a list of context names, how can I access all the variables with the same name across all those contexts?

Tags: symbols, contexts

I'm looking to access variables in different contexts. The contexts are stored in a list labeled `contexttable`. Each context, of course, is a string. Is there any way, without using `NotebookWrite`, to access a variable of the same name, say `x`, in each context?

I am looking for something like

```
 contexttable = {"Context1`", "Context2`", ..., "ContextN`"};
 Map[Print[# <> x]&, contexttable]
```

which would print the `x` variable in each context.

Comment: Look up `Symbol` or `ToExpression` in the docs. Be aware that if the variable you reference does not exist, you will create a new symbol by using those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Leonid Shifrin said in his comment, you can use `SymbolName` and `ToExpression` to get the values in each context.

```
{Context1`x, Context2`x} = {"foo", 42}; 
contexttable = {"Context1`", "Context2`", "Context3`"};
ToExpression[# <> SymbolName @ Unevaluated @ x] & /@ contexttable
```

> {"foo", 42, Context3`x}

Answer (score 0):

Also following Leonid's comment, and borrowing from [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg)'s answer, if you wish to avoid creating new symbols you can use `Names` to filter before passing to `Symbol`:

```
{Context1`x, Context2`x} = {"foo", 42};
contexttable = {"Context1`", "Context2`", "Context3`"};

Symbol /@ Names[# <> "x" & /@ contexttable]
```

> ```
> {"foo", 42}
> ```

Here `` Context3`x `` is never created and only the values for Symbols that exist are returned.  This may or may not be desirable.  If creation of new Symbols is desired just leave out `Names`:

```
Symbol[# <> "x"] & /@ contexttable
```

> ```
> {"foo", 42, Context3`x}
> ```

Note that in each case the symbol name is given as a string, which greatly simplifies things.